# How to display objects in certain time range based on their time property?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm making a project for my university, in which I'm trying to display student's lecture times. I was wondering what would be the best approach to display lecture information in the correct position based by their time property, the lecture's rectangle space should cover the required time range based on the time on the left side.

I've uploaded an image link below, about how I was trying to get it being displayed.

[image]

One of the ideas I had come up with, was dividing the time ranges on the left side to smaller chunks, by about 5 minutes, then specifying by pixels how much  area those 5 minutes will cover. Then taking the lecture time, dividing it by 5 minutes, then multiplying it by the specified pixels for 5 minutes and therefore getting the height of the lecture block.

```
Lecture Object

{
    "title": "Informaciniu sistemu saugumas",
    "type": "Laboratorinis",
    "start_time": "2019-04-30T08:00",
    "end_time": "2019-04-30T09:15",
    "classroom": "503a."
}
```

I would like to be able to display lecture times in the correct position based on their time values.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with those tags when there is no code that relates to any of those? Did you expect us to write code using those technologies (except maybe the JS object literal, but that is only data)? If so, then this question is way too broad. We can try to help when you have a *specific* programming problem, but we would need to see your code and where exactly in that code you are stuck. Please only tag with tags that relate to the code you have a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea:

Make your timetable a table, expanse the table cell to your desire size using `colspan` and `rowspan`

For better features and more complex cases you can use a calendar such as [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), ... instead!

```css
td {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.math {
  background: rgba(100, 122, 200, 0.5)  
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td>8:15</td>
   <td></td>
   <td rowspan="3" class="math"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>8:30</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="display: none"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>8:45</td>
   <td></td>
   <td style="display: none"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>9:00</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```